# Replace text based on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is to dynamically replace the corresponding  text with the string from input field.(field1>field11, field2>field22)

http://jsfiddle.net/c2CUE/3/

Can you give me any clue on how to do it in jquery?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><h2>Field 1</h2>
<input type="text" name="field1" value="qwerty" class="field1"></td>
    <td><span class="field11">asdasd</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td><h2>Field 1</h2>
<input type="text" name="field2" value="qwerty"></td>
      <td><span class="field22">asdasd</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am sure forgot to write your script code

Comment: you want to replace the entire text with what's in the input? or you want to find and replace characters from the span with the content from the input? also are you allowed jQuery or just pure js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.field1").on("keyup",function () {
        $("span.field11").html($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

or in live

http://jsfiddle.net/u8EB9/

you could also hook the function to the "change" event but than youll get your text only updated, after you left the input!
this depends on your needs!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <table>
       <tr>
       <td><h2>Field 1</h2>
           <input type="text" name="field1" value="qwerty" class="field1"></td>
       <td><span class="field11">asdasd</span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td><h2>Field 1</h2>
           <input type="text" name="field2" value="qwerty"></td>
       <td><span class="field22">asdasd</span></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.field11').html($('.field1').val());
        $('.field22').html($('.field2').val());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your intention is to use this code multiple times it might be better to use `class`s rather than `id`'s to stop you needing to create a bunch of bind events.

html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h2>Field 1</h2>
      <input type="text" name="field1" value="qwerty" class="replacer" />
      <input type="button" class="replace" value="replace" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="replacee field11">asdasd</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <h2>Field 1</h2>
        <input type="text" class="replacer" name="field2" value="qwerty" />
        <input type="button" class="replace" value="replace" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="replacee field22">asdasd</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.replace').on('click', function(){
    var parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    parentRow.find('.replacee').text(parentRow.find('.replacer').val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2CUE/4/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><h2>Field 1</h2>
<input type="text" name="field1" value="qwerty" class="field1"></td>
    <td><span class="field11">asdasd</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td><h2>Field 1</h2>
<input type="text" name="field2" value="qwerty"></td>
      <td><span class="field22">asdasd</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("input[type='text']").on("keyup",function () {
        $(this).parent().next().find('span').html($(this).val());
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/F74ec/